# How to Formate a date in model and display on view using get, instead of using String.Format in MVC view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Currently, I am using **<%= String.Format("{0:MMM dd, yyyy}", DateTime.Now)%>** to get today's date in **Jul 27, 2011** format.

Now, I want to get today's date from model instead of using String.Format in my view (whic is not a good way).

Anyone can help me how to do this in Model.

I am using Asp.net MVC2.

I tried in my property something like:

```
[DisplayName("Display Date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}")] 
public DateTime DisplayDate { get; set; }
```

And in view i tried:

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DisplayDate) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird, the following works great for me.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DisplayDate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            DisplayDate = DateTime.Now
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DisplayDate) %>
```

Output HTML:

```
Jul 27, 2011
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use:

```
<%= DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy") %>
```

But, why is `String.Format` bad?

Comment: String.Format is not good because for consistency and maintainability it's good to have in Model or ViewModel.